# Placing external dependencies in a JavaScript closure - Pros and Cons

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, closures

I've gotten into the pattern of placing all dependenices that my JavaScript function depends on in the closure of the [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript).

**Pros**

- There's a small performance boost when accessing the variable reference in the closure, rather than climbing up the lexical scope to the root/window object.
- Another small performance boost if you have namespaced variables that get a little long (i.e. app.calculator.fileExporter), which can be referenced by the variable in the closure (i.e. calcFileExporter). [JsPerf Reference](https://jsperf.com/namespace-vs-global-methods)
- A clear, at a glance view at the external classes/functions used.

**Cons**

- It can be hard to maintain, and can be hard to be consistent. i.e. Do
  I really feel like adding another external closure reference, just to
  use this one call?
- Larger memory footprint. I'm not sure how large, but there's a larger memory footprint due to this.

My question is:

1. Is there concern over a large memory footprint. (i.e. 50+ classes, all having ~3 closure reference variables). These are just insignificant pointers, low in size, right?
2. Is this a recommended pattern? I've seen this used for the jQuery/$ , but not often used for other objects.

Example:

```
app.calc.fileExporter = (function (document, localStorageWrapper, calcFileImporter) {

    // Do some stuff!

}(window.document, app.localStorageWrapper, app.calc.fileImporter));
```